# Should I override Security::_crypt() for using blowfish in Cakephp 2.4.5?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

_crypt() in Cakephp 2.4.5 uses **$2a$** but it is recommended to use **$2y$** instead of **$2a$** as one can read about it here, http://www.php.net/security/crypt_blowfish.php. It seems that _crypt() is not going to be modified in Cakephp 2.x as it’s been modified in Cakephp 3.0.
Here’s _crypt() from **Cakephp 2.4.5**:

```
protected static function _crypt($password, $salt = false) {
    if ($salt === false) {
        $salt = self::_salt(22);
        $salt = vsprintf('$2a$%02d$%s', array(self::$hashCost, $salt));
    }

    if ($salt === true || strpos($salt, '$2a$') !== 0 || strlen($salt) < 29) {
        trigger_error(__d(
            'cake_dev',
            'Invalid salt: %s for %s Please visit http://www.php.net/crypt and read the appropriate section for building %s salts.',
            array($salt, 'blowfish', 'blowfish')
        ), E_USER_WARNING);
        return '';
    }
    return crypt($password, $salt);
}
```

And here’s _crypt() from **Cakephp 3.0**:

```
   protected static function _crypt($password, $salt = false) {
     if ($salt === false) {
        $salt = static::_salt(22);
        $salt = vsprintf('$2y$%02d$%s', array(static::$hashCost, $salt));
    }

    if ($salt === true || strpos($salt, '$2y$') !== 0 || strlen($salt) < 29) {
        throw new Error\Exception(sprintf(
            'Invalid salt: %s for blowfish Please visit http://www.php.net/crypt and read the appropriate section for building blowfish salts.',
            $salt
        ));
    }
    return crypt($password, $salt);
}
```

What will I break if I use the code of _crypt() from Cakephp 3.0 for overriding _crypt() in Cakephp 2.4.5? They are almost the same.
I’m new to Cakephp and need some advice.

Comment: IS this for a new development or do you have data already in the db?

Comment: It's for new development.